# What is the source for the midrash about Jewish soldiers escaping to Romania?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, midrash

Specifically, looking for the midrash quoted by Radaq to Shoftim 20:15 as saying that the missing 1,000 Jewish soldiers "escaped to Romania."

Thanks!

Comment: I beileve its referring to Rome

Comment: Since you seem to be asking about a particular midrash, I changed the title of the question to match. If you had meant to ask about midrashim on Shoftim in general, you can either roll back the edit or ask a new question

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14264#p=336&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=

Comment: Do you refer to the verse כֵּן תַּעֲשֶׂה לְכָל הֶעָרִים הָרְחֹקֹת מִמְּךָ מְאֹד אֲשֶׁר לֹא מֵעָרֵי הַגּוֹיִם הָאֵלֶּה הֵנָּה or to the verse וַיִּתְפָּקְדוּ בְנֵי בִנְיָמִן בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא מֵהֶעָרִים עֶשְׂרִים וְשִׁשָּׁה אֶלֶף אִישׁ שֹׁלֵף חָרֶב לְבַד מִיֹּשְׁבֵי הַגִּבְעָה הִתְפָּקְדוּ שְׁבַע מֵאוֹת אִישׁ בָּחוּר?

Comment: The latter. And simyou I saw the radak, I just don't know what medrash he's referring to (he doesn't say).